# Proving General Markov Property

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $\left(x_{n}\right)$ be a stochastic process with state space $\mathcal{X}$. Then we have two def of the Markov Property:

1. It has the simple Markov property if for any Borel measurable set $A$ of $\mathcal{X},$ any $n \geq 0$
   $$
   \mathbb{P}\left(x_{n+1} \in A \mid x_{0}, \ldots x_{n}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(x_{n+1} \in A \mid x_{n}\right) 
   $$
2. It has the general Markov property (with respect to a filtration $\mathcal{F}_{t}$), if $x_{t}$ is adapted to $\mathcal{F}_{t}$ and if for any measurable subset $A$ of $\mathcal{X},$ any $s, t \in I,$ $t>s$
   $$
   \mathbb{P}\left(x_{t} \in A \mid \mathcal{F}_{s}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(x_{t} \in A \mid x_{s}\right) $$

I think the two definitions are equivalent when we are dealing with the natural filtration i.e. $\mathcal{F}_{n} = \sigma\{x_0, x_1 \dots x_n\}$. It is obvious that (2) implies (1), however I'm not sure how to prove it the other way. Is this even true? I have to show given (1), we have for $t>s$:

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(x_{t} \in A \mid x_0, x_1, \dots x_s \right)=\mathbb{P}\left(x_{t} \in A \mid x_{s}\right)
$$